# How to serve media across home network?

Tags: networking, file-sharing, media, dlna

I'm looking to share my media across my home network. Router fully supports running a DLNA server, but I don't know if it'd be better to run the server from my main server computer instead of from the router, as the router would have to operate off of a network share and my server can operate directly off of the files.

Here's what I need to serve, in order of importance: ISO 1:1 DVD rips (4-8GB files), MP4/H.264 encoded videos, MKV videos, MP3 files, JPEG/CR2 images. Maybe I'm completely ludicrous for wanting to push full DVD files across my network, but in reality, I would assume that only the parts of the actual file needed (ie: menu, main video payload for main title) would be served at any one time. Plus, encoding takes time and precious disk space, so why not stream it 1:1 ;)

Does anyone know of the best way to accomplish this? Main goal is to serve it to Logitech Revue downstairs and secondary goal is to serve it to other computers in the house. For music, I assume I could run a DAAP server, but I don't think that the Revue supports that (and I can't exactly throw together an app that does it just yet).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I use [PS3 Media Server](http://ps3mediaserver.blogspot.com/) on my main machine for serving media from both my NAS and the local disk to my Bravia. Only thing I had to do was point it to the folders I wanted it to serve from, it was dead simple. As long as everything is DLNA certified, then it should be fine.

Comment: Freaking brilliant! I didn't know PS3 media server ran on operating systems other than PS3 when I was searching. This thing does __EVERYTHING!__ \m/

Comment: Glad I could help.